# Checking the Media player

Tags: android

If i am playing song from a song list and if the other song is already playing then both songs plays simultaneously in android studio. If i just use next or previous buttons then they are working fine. The problem is through song list. I am not getting how to check if media player is playing already or not in this condion. I am doing this code in kotlin and i am new user of android studio.

Comment: Please show us your efforts in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this way

```
You can take a global variable of MediaPlayer
```

public  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
and then create in onCreate method:

```
mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxxx);
```

and thus your play method will be:

```
public void mediaPlay(View view) {

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    else{
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```